# Justification of an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t,3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am wondering if the following is true:

$$\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t,3)\cong\mathbb{Z}/3.$$

I can tell that the ideal $(t,3)$ is maximal. In contrast, the ideal $(t^2,2t)$ is not even irreducible. So it's less likely that we can simplify $\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2,2t)$ further.

If the aforementioned isomorphism is true, that means $\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t,3)\cong(\mathbb{Z}[t]/t)/(3)\cong\mathbb{Z}/3$, where the $(3)$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[t]/t$. My questions are:

1) Is this argument legitimate?

2) If it is true, is there any theorem justifying the aforementioned isomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your intuition is correct and I try to explain necessary steps:

> **Claim.** $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x,3\rangle\cong\Bbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle$

Well, I'll prove the following steps:

$$\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x,3\rangle\cong \frac{\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x\rangle}{\langle x,3\rangle/\langle x\rangle} \cong\Bbb{Z}/\langle 3\rangle$$

- The first isomorphism is due to the **2nd Isomorphism Theorem** of Ring theory.
- I think $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x\rangle \cong \Bbb{Z}$ is clear. (Hint: consider the homomorphism $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$ form $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ to $\Bbb{Z}$ and use **1st Isomorphism Theorem on Rings**.
- Now for the equality $\langle x,3\rangle/\langle x\rangle\cong \langle 3\rangle$ Try to define the homomorphism as follows:

$\phi :\langle x,3\rangle \to \langle 3\rangle$ by mapping any element $xf(x)+3g(x)\in \langle x,3 \rangle$ to $3g(0) \in \langle 3\rangle$ (**N.B.** Here, $f,g \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$), i.e. $$\phi: xf(x)+3g(x) \mapsto 3g(0)$$

See that this is an **epimorphism**. Also $\ker \phi=\langle x\rangle$. Then by **1st Isomorphism theorem** $\langle x,3\rangle/\ker \phi \cong \langle 3\rangle$. Which justifies all your steps...!!

**N.B.** To find out the $\ker \phi$, remember for any $g(x)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ if we have $g(0)=0$ that means $x$ is a factor of $g$ and so $g\in \langle x\rangle$.

Comment: $>$ is an operator; &\rangle$ is a grouping symbol. They have different formatting rules, and are the reason for all the weird spaces in your answer.

Comment: @BobKrueger...Thanks for mentioning that....I'll take care of it next time....:)

Comment: What's wrong with using the [edit] function to fix it *this time* as well? Is your time somehow more important than that of someone who might have edited this?

Comment: I’ll note that I didn’t edit it so that the poster would recognize the mistake. @IndrajitGhosh happy to help even if it’s not expressly math.

Answer (score 2):

It's legitimate and a consequence of the [isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).